# Typeerror: 'undefined' for select2 in grails gsp

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp, jquery-select2

I am using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#basics)  for setting up fields used for tagging support for my application in my grails project.

In html I have included

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'select2.css')}"  type="text/css">
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="../js/select2.js"></script>
  <div class="select2-container select2-container-multi populate placeholder" id="s2id_e2_2" style="width: 250px"> 
     <select id="e2_2" name="majorSkills" multiple="multiple" style="width: 250px; display: 'Select Major Skills'; " class="populate placeholder"><option></option>
            <optgroup label="Java">
                <option value="j2ee">J2EE</option>
                <option value="hibernate">Hibernate</option>
                <option value="spring">Spring</option>

            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="ERP">
                <option value="sap">SAP</option>
                <option value="peoplesoft">Peoplesoft</option>

            </optgroup>

        </select>
        </div>
```

In my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#e2_2").select2({
                placeholder: "Select a State"
            });
});
```

**js and css files are included but and error shown up in console is**

```
select2.js:33  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#e2_2").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a State"
    })')
```

Can anyone help me to fix these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select2 requires jquery. It looks like you didn't include it.

Comment: No. I have included `<g:setProvider library="jquery" />` on the corresponding template gsp file

Comment: what happens when you evaluate the following in console:   `jQuery`

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery @select2.js line no:43

Comment: ok, so jquery was not included on the page. can you look in your html and see if you can find it there, and if the javascript file actually points at a js file?

Comment: yes, on the page also, the jquery  is been included, i Can see the jquery contents(js)files included correctly

Answer (score 1):

I have included the jquery - js first and then select2.js in the next l so that it worked out for me,

Thanks for the answer and suggestion - [mkoryak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26188/mkoryak)